# Search by multiple strings using SQLFunction.Difference with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This works great when the input is a single string

In this example "Lorem ipsum"

```
dbContext.NewsArticles.Where(article => SQLFunction.Difference(article.Text, "Lorem ipsum") == 3).ToArray()
```

How can I search by multiple strings? In other words, the input is a string[] or List

```
var input = new List<string>{
 "Lorem ipsum dolor",
 "elementum lacinia",
 "cursus nulla molestie",
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: The two ways I know of to handle this in SQL is via a User-Defined Table Type on the SQL server, which would allow you to pass a table to the query, or a comma-separated string which would be split out via a custom-made SQL function to return a table variable. I don't think EF plays nicely with UDTTs, so the function might be the best bet.

Comment: Have you tried `.Where(article => input.Any(x => SQLFunction.Difference(article.Text, x) == 3))`?

Comment: @juharr it works. add it as an answer and Ill select it. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use that list with `Any`.

```
dbContext.NewsArticles
    .Where(article => input.Any(x => SQLFunction.Difference(article.Text, x) == 3))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: will adding an index to the column NewsArticles.Text in SQL Server improve performance?

Comment: @Jasmine I doubt it since this is not an exact match comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the table and data type/size of the text column. Partitioning the table on a date (if that is an option and depending on data distribution) might provide positive results when the query plan results in a parallel query.

Comment: it's nvarchar(max), I would like to know if adding an index will improve soundex/difference performance

Comment: I do not believe adding an index in this scenario where you are *only* filtering on the text column using Difference will help in any meaningful way. Unless someone else proposes a better solution for this single filter query, it might be worthwhile to look in to possibly expanding the filter criteria to improve performance, or possibly capture and index a separate table with common misspellings. I suppose it depends on what is acceptable in your particular scenario.